# Good open source SQL Parsers?

Tags: sql, parsing

Java application needs to support databases Oracle, DB2, and MSS. Syntax for some of the queries that involve sql functions have varied syntax in different databases. Example: NULLIF() in oracle might not work for MSS. Are there any open source SQL parsers that can parse and convert the query string into db specific sql?

Comment: Guess it's unlikely to have OSS tool to have any close to exhaustive support for such purposes for commercial products. Not only SQL dialects differ, but there are proprietary important extensions, like a way to specify hints to SQL planner.

Answer (score 1):

jOOQ has a SQL parser that can do exactly what you're looking for. You can see the online version here: https://www.jooq.org/translate. The parser can also work as a [CLI](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/sql-parser-cli/) or [API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/sql-parser-api/). An example:

```java
System.out.println(
    DSL.using(SQLSERVER, new Settings()
            .withParseDialect(ORACLE)
            .withTransformTableListsToAnsiJoin(true))
        .parser()
        .parse("select nvl(a.z, 1) from a, b, c where a.x = b.x(+) and a.y = c.y")
);
```

This would print:

```sql
select coalesce(A.Z, 1)
from A
  join C
    on A.Y = C.Y
  left outer join B
    on A.X = B.X;
```

jOOQ is Open Source for open source RDBMS and has commercial drivers for other database products. I know you were probably looking for an all OSS library, I can only offer you a partially OSS one, and maybe someone else will find this late answer useful.

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ.

Answer (score 0):

@hd1 has the right question: what are you trying to accomplish? Because if your target is not to parse the SQL, just use different DBs for storing entities, there are for example the [JPA (Java Persistence API)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) libraries supporting [JPQL (Java Persistence Query Language)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_Query_Language), that is database agnostic (or is supposed to be).

Links:

- [Eclipselink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/)
- [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/)

Comment: No, it is not a matter of using different dbs to store entities. My requirement is to be able to parse the sql string and make it work across all the three databases.